# extensions xsl and intl are missing (need them to run Magento2). I'm using Windows 8.1

Tags: xslt, xampp, magento2, php-7, intl

I installed `php7.0.15/apache2.4.25/phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2 via xampp`, but it turns out that the extensions `xsl` and `intl` are missing (need them to run `Magento2`).
I'm using `Windows 8.1`.

Both files `php_xsl.dll` and `php_intl.dll` exist in `xampp/php/ext` and I tried deleting the related `";" from extension=..` from in `php.ini`,

re-saving the php.ini and restarting apache server;

also copied in apache/bin folder the `icu*.dll` files from php;

BUT no success with that: still missing with magento2 Readiness Check.
Have any advise?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you---

**No.1**

Are you restarting the apache as `administrator` as I forget to do that most of the time.

**No.2**

Check your environment variable path. Did you set it properly.

Hope this can help!